# how to get the suitable linux commands for android ?

Tags: android, linux, command, android-wifi, wifi-direct

i need to know what are linux commands used for WIFI DIRECT in android ?
i am confused in these commands at this  [link](http://dishingtech.blogspot.com/2012/01/realtek-wi-fi-direct-programming-guide.html).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jodes
i need to measure the RSSI between two peers with WIFI direct

Comment: so i need the kernel commands